# Layout guide to exactly accomodate the iPhone X, XR/XS, 11 notch

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, safearealayoutguide

I am trying to make a landscape orientation app that slides a left shelf in (on the side of the iPhone X notch). I want the content to feel centered in the width of this shelf UIView. However, I also don't want the shelf content to be covered by the notch.

I have looked into using `safeAreaLayoutGuide`. However, the problem is that the bounds of this Safe Area Layout Guide do not hug the edge of the notch. There is space in between.

What I want is a layout guide similar to `safeAreaLayoutGuide` that takes into account the notch, but nothing else.

A desirable solution would allow me the flexibility of creating a filled in box whose left edge starts exactly at the notch. No extra space, nothing else. Moreover, it should not involve inputting a single constant.

[image]